# Perl `uc` function oneliner -p/-n difference?

Tags: perl

It works as intended:

```
perl -ne "print uc" /etc/passwd
```

But following isn't (it just prints in original case":

```
perl -pe uc /etc/passwd
```

I don't understand what's wrong with it.

thanks.

Comment: SOLVED: `perl -pe '$_=uc' ...`

Answer (score 2):

You're doing different things. So it's not surprising that you get different results.

In the first example, you take the value of `$_`, pass it to `uc` and print the results (which is an upper case version of the original text).

In the second example, you take the value of `$_`, pass it to `uc` and print the value in `$_`. But you've done nothing to update `$_` so you get the unaltered value. The fix (as you've already noted in a comment) is to update `$_` with the value that is returned by `uc`.

```
perl -pe '$_ = uc' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: You can use `perl -MO=Deparse ...` to see exactly what's happening under-the-covers.